# n is+ve integer, how many solutions $(x,y)$ exist for $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{n}$ with $x$, $y$ being positive integers and $(x \neq y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I wanted to know, how can i solve this.

For a given positive integer n, how many solutions $(x,y)$ exist for $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{n}$ with $x$ and $y$ being positive integers and $(x \neq y)$.

Comment: Possibly related to Project Euler problems 108/110: https://projecteuler.net/problem=108

Comment: @labbhattacharjee i didn't knew that it has been asked before.

Comment: @SamSharma, it's not easy to find duplicate here. I could recount because I answered it:)

Comment: I am going to edit the title of the duplicate question, because it would not be immediately obvious to someone approaching this for the first time that they were the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(x,y)$ is a solution of $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ = $\frac{1}{n}$ then $x>n$ and $y>n$.
We can write the equation as

$n(x+y)=xy$ = $(x-n)(y-n) = n^2$

and for any $k$ positive $k|n^2$, therefore the solutions are given by $x-n=k$ and $y-n=\frac{n^2}{k}$ or $x=n+k$ and $y=n+\frac{n^2}{k}$.

The only case for $x=y$ is when $n=k$, therefore the number of solutions for $(x,y)$ with $(x\neq y)$ is $d(n^2)-1$ where $d(n^2)$ is the number of divisors of $n^2.$

Answer (score 4):

It is clear that the two positive fractions on the left have to be less than $\frac 1n$, so we have $x,y \gt n$.

Let $x=n+a, y=n+b$ and clear fractions then $$n(n+b)+n(n+a)=(n+a)(n+b)$$ which simplifies to $$ab=n^2$$

Any such $a,b$ give a pair of fractions.